# Getting the error 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'revoke'

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, google-python-api

I'm using Google Calendar OAuth2 login. Now once the user is successfully logged in, I'd like to revoke the credentials token on clicking a link.

The official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) says that the code below revokes the token

```
credentials.revoke(httplib2.Http())
```

However, I'm getting the error -

'Credentials' object has no attribute 'revoke'

Could someone help figure this out? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share code for how you got your credentials?

Comment: Sure, here it is